# How to extract data from Plex ERP?

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, erp

My company uses Plex ERP and I was wondering if I could somehow connect to it to extract data and create necessary dassboards for better visualization. However, i have never used an ERP system and I lack the knowledge on how to connect to Plex ERP. I tried to use python but I hit a roadblock. Can anyone guide me on this? I just want a start here so that I can get a direction. Is it possible to directly integrate Plex ERP and PowerBi using an odbc connection?